# Date in calculated field not separating data

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

What I'm trying to do is list all of the data in a specific table. I tried these code snippets shown, and I still get data from outside the range (2005, etc.)

This was the first one I tried

```
=IIF((Fields!APP_CREATE_DATETIME.Value >="{ts '2014-01-01 00:00:00'}") AND (Fields!APP_CREATE_DATETIME.Value > "{ts '2014-01-31 00:00:00'}"), Switch(Fields!DLR_NAME.Value, "JAN"), nothing)
```

Then this

```
=IIF((Fields!APP_CREATE_DATETIME.Value >="2014-01-01 00:00:00") AND (Fields!APP_CREATE_DATETIME.Value > "2014-01-31 00:00:00"), Switch(Fields!DLR_NAME.Value, "JAN"), nothing)
```

The SQL column in the table itself is of `DATETIME` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there but that isn't the right syntax for `Switch()`

```
=SWITCH(Conditional1, Result1,
    Conditional2, Result2,
    Conditional3, Result3
)
```

I think it would be easier to set two filters on the table. One for greater than the start date and the other for less than the end date. It would be much easier to understand and maintain. But that is mostly because it seems to be a simple date range filtering if the `SWITCH()` doesn't actually do anything.

---

I'd recommend using the `DateSerial()` function in order to generate the date rather than relying on trying to properly convert a string value. Otherwise you'll need to use the `CDATE()` function to convert the string, but string dates always just feel a little unreliable to me.

```
=DateSerial(1970,1,1)
```

or

```
=Cdate("1970-01-01")
```

Comment: You're right. Ive omitted the switch as it was worthless. I guess my question is how I would format the dates for filter. Because I get that Cannot compare data of types System.DateTime and System.String error even though the values I've inputted at DATETIME format

Comment: Updated with info about string to date conversion.

Comment: Thanks. Dateserial worked. Rookie mistake by not realizing despite looking like a date its still considered a string.